# Why some MySQL data type require some extra bytes?

Tags: mysql, size

[image]

I was reading about the MySQL data type size. I saw VARCHAR takes extra 1/2 bytes, MEDIUMTEXT requires extra 3 bytes, LONGTEXT requires extra 4 bytes. What is the reason for such MySQL behaviour?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because this is covered elsewhere

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When MySQL (or any database or computer language) stores a variable length string, there are basically two ways to store the value:

- The length can be encoded followed by the characters in the string
- The end of the string can be marked by a special character (typically `'0'`)

Databases (almost?) always use length encoding.  So, when you store `'ABC'` as a variable length string, in the database storage it looks like:

```
3  A  B  C
```

When you store `'A'`:

```
1  A
```

That way, MySQL knows when one string ends and the next begins.  The different lengths for the different types are based on the maximum length of the string.  So, 1 byte can hold values from 0 to 255.  2 bytes can hold values from 0 to 65,535 and so on.

When you use a regular character expression, say `char(3)`, then `'ABC'` looks like:

```
A   B   C
```

This occupies three bytes/whatever (depending on the character coding).  The length is known from the table metadata.

With `char(3)`, the string `'A'` also occupies three slots:

```
A        
---^space here
--------^space here
```

The extra two are occupied by spaces.  For long strings, this is generally a big waste of space, which is why most strings are stored as `varchar` rather than `char`.

Comment: Thanks for answer but why VARCHAR requires sometime 1 byte and sometime 2 bytes and why CHAR doesn't requires extra byte?

Comment: @VarunAgw . . . Read the last paragraph to understand why `varchar` sometimes uses one byte and sometimes 2.  `char` doesn't require an extra byte because the length is known:  the number of characters in the string is stored in the database and the length is known from the format of the table.